# Port Forwarding Between 2 Internet Machines

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

Here's my scenario:

### Setup

There are 3 machines:

`A`: on the internet : has ip (`a.a.a.a`), has port `pa` open

`B`: my server / gateway : has ip (`b.b.b.b`), has port `pb` open

`C`: on the internet : has ip (`c.c.c.c`), has port `pc` open

### Constraints

The owner of machine `A` offers a service via port `pa` that must be accessed on machine `C` via port `pc`. The problem is, the owner of `A` can only allow to directly connect with my server, machine `B` on port `pb`.

Note that, *`A` and `C` are on the internet*, so in effect, I have to act as a gateway between two machines on the internet (the literature I've found in most firewall docs concerns acting as a gateway *between the internet and your local* network).

### Requirements

My task is to make sure I give machine `C` the service offered by `A` via my server `B`, in such a way that traffic from `A:pa` ends up on `C:pc` and traffic from `C:pc` ends up on `A:pa`.

So, how can I achieve this, say using `iptables` or another Linux / Unix utility? Is it even possible?

### Hypothetical Solution:

Here's an Idea I have in mind, but am not sure it's legit or makes sense:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --source a.a.a.a --source-port pa \
--destination b.b.b.b --destination-port pb -j DNAT --to-destination c.c.c.c:pc
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --source c.c.c.c --source-port pc \
--destination b.b.b.b --destination-port pb -j DNAT --to-destination a.a.a.a:pa
```

Comment: what does 'on the internet' exactly mean? which of these IPs are RFC-1918 (private)? how does each of the machines reach the other one (A<>B<>C, routing-wiese)?